# WSO2 script mediator is slow

Tags: javascript, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm trying to use scripting mediator in WSO2 ESB to transform a JSON message.  It seems really slow in comparison to the routing filter with JSON.

Is there a particular reason behind that? Or why it's slower by so much?  Also is there a faster way that you've found to work?

Any feedback at all is very much appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve using the script mediator? Based on your requirement you may make use of other mechanisms such as XSLT transformation.

Comment: The ESB is to take in a JSON payload, transform it (can be by scripting or anything else), and then return the payload (still as JSON)